# Employee max Salary

Tags: sql, group-by, max

I need to get max Salary in each department for each record

Input:

```
+-----+-------+-------+-----+
| Eid | Ename | Dname | sal |
+-----+-------+-------+-----+
|   1 | a     | d1    | 100 |
|   2 | b     | d1    | 500 |
|   3 | c     | d2    | 600 |
|   4 | e     | d3    | 700 |
+-----+-------+-------+-----+
```

Output:

```
+-----+-------+-------+-----+----------+
| Eid | Ename | Dname | sal | max(sal) |
+-----+-------+-------+-----+----------+
|   1 | a     | d1    | 100 |      500 |
|   2 | b     | d1    | 500 |      500 |
|   3 | c     | d2    | 600 |      600 |
|   4 | e     | d3    | 700 |      700 |
+-----+-------+-------+-----+----------+
```

How to get output using sql?

Comment: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Answer (score 4):

With `MAX()` window function:

```
SELECT t.*,
  MAX(t.sal) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Dname) max_sal
FROM tablename t
```

If your database does nor support window functions:

```
SELECT t.*, d.max_sal
FROM tablename t INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Dname, MAX(sal) max_sal
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY Dname
) d ON d.Dname = t.Dname
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=6ac447adad401221e12ae8c30b7cfb04).
Results:

```
> eid | ename | dname | sal | max_sal
> --: | :---- | :---- | --: | ------:
>   1 | a     | d1    | 100 |     500
>   2 | b     | d1    | 500 |     500
>   3 | c     | d2    | 600 |     600
>   4 | e     | d3    | 700 |     700
```